# Downsize Flex to Rigid Duct

Tags: hvac, ducts

I have the AC air handler in a pretty tight spot in my home.  It's a bit hard to tell in the picture but main return for the system comes in a 12-inch flex duct and makes this tight S shape to connect to the air handler.  When fully connected the 12-inch flex is pressed against the side of the air handler otherwise it does not fit.  I think I can get about an 8-inch rigid duct in that area and without bumping into the box but is that enough airflow, or is it downsized too much from 12inch (which I assume isnt nearly as efficient with all the bends and smushing)

Other notes:

- In the picture I have removed the return register to access the space
- This picture is the top view of the unit
- There is one other return branch, but this is the one most central to
  the house (stairwell between first and second floor)

[image]

Comment: I know you can downsize since ridgid pipe is considerably smoother on the interior than the flex pipe, giving it much less static pressure. I do not know what the equivalent is. 8 inch may be pushing the idea too far without checking into it farther. From my end, it is impossible to tell how much the 12" flex was squished to say the 8" will work. You may be able to extend the trunk line out more, and tap into the side, instead of using an elbow.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think to modify the trunk and use a new hole

Comment: As a mention, depending on where the HVAC unit is and where the opening into the room is, flex duct separates the unit from the ductwork so the vibration does not transmit into the house. If you use rigid duct, the noise might be considerably louder than before, since the smooth inside will not baffle the sound like the corrugated pipe does. There are isolator rings to add in the duct run to solve the vibration part.